# Spring 2018 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Yes, spring is in the air, and a Stack Overflow's thoughts turn to **new moderators!** This post concludes the auspicious **[tenth moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10)** on Stack Overflow - not counting those two other elections we ran prior to election number one.

The votes are in, the results have been tallied, and the winners are...

[image: Rob] [image: Samuel Liew]   [image: Yvette Colomb]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/3956566.png))</sub>

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5229219307061248/0).

Please take a minute to pay a heartfelt thanks to *everyone* who stepped up to run in this election - it's a major commitment and anyone willing to help shoulder the weight should be appreciated, particularly a crew as experienced and insightful as those who nominated this year.

Finally, please join me in wishing a fond farewell to veteran moderators [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) and [Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/elixenide), who've served the site faithfully since 2015. Thank them for their work and wish them well in their next great work!

---

### Update July 9th, 2018: the triumphant return of Ed

Ed Cottrell, after stepping down in March, found himself with time to spare and a desire to continue serving - so we've welcomed him back four months later. Thanks Ed!

Comment: Are we going to have additional people called up after the election to meet additional demand, because it's a net gain of just one mod?

Comment: @gparyani We can probably rely on the three new mods to be over-achievers for at least a few weeks, and do the work of 6 people :)

Comment: @gparyani Nah, we push the new mods to the limits.

Comment: Congratulations to all three who made it. And thanks to all who ran. That was a close run for the third seat!

Comment: What... I thought I was going to win. _shrugs_

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods, all my three choices won, yay!

Comment: Suckers! Coffee break's over, back on yer heads!

Comment: Thanks, Shog9! It's been real. I'm looking forward to continuing to contribute to the site without the ♦.

Comment: So, if I interpret these results right, the difference between Yvette and Brett was 17 votes? That's cutting it really close!

Comment: Congrats! I didn't even realize it until I opened their profiles, but all 3 are Aussies!

Comment: Congrats guys, seems like the Aussies are coming, eek! @Yvette all those things I said about you were just a joke, I've always said people from Australia are lovely (apart from the cricketers of course) ;)

Comment: I voted, and none of my 3 choices were elected. What do I do now? Should I be dissatisfied? Should I ruminate over my "poor choice" of candidates? Should I consider running in the next one so I have no one to blame but myself next time? Well, I suppose that's life in a democracy. Congrats to all elected moderators!

Comment: Spring? No, for Australians it is autumn.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I used to live in Western Australia and I recall this being close to the end of the "wet season". Wet in the sense that [local plantlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triodia_(grass)) could hope to absorb a bit of rainfall before it evaporated. But it's a big country and I gather some bits of it have four seasons. ;-)

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators. May you moderate well and justly! And thank you to Matt and Ed!

Comment: I feel like there some missing information here. Wth happened to Matt & Ed?

Comment: They decided to step down, @K.Dᴀᴠɪs; they're welcome to chat more about their reasons if they wish to. Should they ever wish to return to moderation, they're more than welcome to.

Comment: Congrats all three guys for getting elected , and better luck others for next election .

Comment: Brett, I wish you get elected next time. :)

Comment: Congratulations to all of you, specially Yvette who didn't step down after not being elected last time.

Comment: Why did Brett DeWoody not seelcted?

Comment: Could someone explain what exactly happens in rounds 8 to 13? Why not just continue with eliminating the person with the least votes in round 8 (Brett) and finish up in round 9? Also congratulations to the winners ofc.

Comment: Australians have hacked the election!!!!!! It was them all along!

Comment: @Pekka웃  https://www.smh.com.au/business/consumer-affairs/the-former-cambridge-analytica-figures-working-in-australia-20180323-p4z5y7.html

Comment: @mcalex it all makes sense now.

Comment: @yvette Horses, now unicorns and ponies. Small step for mankind...

Comment: @SteffenWinkler If i understand it correctly, the point is that if, for instance, a voter's second choice vote on Rob isn't necessary to elect him (because Rob had already crossed the threshold when it was added to his tally) the voter's third choice vote will not be disregarded. [Here is a fuller explanation of the system](http://blog.opavote.com/2017/04/meek-stv-explained.html).

Comment: hm, wouldn't it be easier to just remove anyone who passed the threshold and transfer all their votes according to 2nd or 3rd vote choice and continue until a third candidate manages to pass through the threshold? Otherwise who decides whose vote is 'moved'? As it stands if the last 500(for example) votes counted towards someone that just passed the threshold all have the same 2nd/3rd vote this would skew the result if that helps that person cross the threshold.

Comment: Awesome. It was the first time I voted and I found the process super-clear and easy :D

Comment: @Steffen "Otherwise who decides whose vote is 'moved'?" - a small fraction of everyone's vote is moved. That's what the "Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the threshold" part is: everyone who voted for Rob has now voted for him 0.94 and their second choice 0.06, unless that was Samuel Liew and then a fraction of that will be passed on to their third choice.

Comment: @Rup ah, that explains a lot. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Yvette Colomb and Brett DeWoody were so close... I wonder in such a situation, shouldn't there be four moderators elected? Anyway i'm sure they would both help a lot. Then again, i'm not questioning the election process.

Comment: I hope Brett DeWoody runs again next time.  That was such a close one!  Congratulations, new mods!

Comment: @Froopy Having received 99.74% of the votes of the last past the post, I think he stands a good chance if he does. Their weighted difference is 17 votes with each receiving ~6500.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Rules are rules, we can't go changing them just because we think something different after the results are calculated. Also, who says we need 4 mods? I'm sure Brett will run again next time considering how close he was. After all, Yvette came close last time too.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Last time Yvette was too close. She'd have won if there was third seat.

Comment: I voted for Rob, Samuel and both are elected. :-)

Comment: **Congratulations** to all you for being elected as a moderator in the *tenth moderator election*. Hope you will hold the bonding of the community and serve the community effectively. Cheers!!!

Comment: A-ha-ha, Australia rocks!!! Congratulations! ;)

Comment: I expected Putin will be elected... An exception has been thrown! 

Comment: Congrats to the new mods! The same three people I voted for :D

Comment: @GertArnold yes a small trot for unicorns ;)

Comment: Grats to Yvette, Samuel and Rob, and thank you for picking up this task!

Comment: That is a very good pool of moderators… Welcome to all!

Comment: I don't really understand how the votes were counted on [this page](https://www.opavote.com/results/5229219307061248/0). What's "exhausted"? How is that way of counting different from just selecting the top 3 candidates in round 1? Could someone please explain how that works?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Read [duoplode's replies to Steffan starting here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365198/spring-2018-community-moderator-election-results/365219?noredirect=1#comment568894_365198)

Comment: Congrats to the mods. Good to see two of the users I voted for.

Comment: The 3 I voted for got elected. It is a pattern now.
Maybe SO can just let me elect the mods every year and save everyone time.

Comment: Using any Condorcet system, Brett would have been chosen — there are no cycles in the pairwise graph, 8914 ballots rank Brett over Yvette, and 8304 ballots rank Yvette over Brett. But STV does this thing where ballots that have Yvette second and Brett third (or vice-versa) have their value multiplied by an effectively-random factor depending on the performance of their first choice.

Comment: Well, what do you know. All 3 mods I voted for got elected, and all 3 are Aussie. Being Australian myself I'm obviously quite excited.

Comment: Interesting that they're all Aussies? :P

Comment: Thanks for being willing to step up! StackOverflow wouldn't be the same without the mods dedication to keep everything clean and running smoothing :)

Comment: Congrats all of you :)

Comment: Congrats to all three of you. Hope that we can make the community a better place with the help of you guys. To help people and solve their problems in a clear form and strategy in every possible way. Let us always help each other and stay united! Wish you luck!

Comment: All three from Australia!!! Congratulations to all three of you!

Comment: _"479,354 voters were eligible, 226,336 visited the site during the election, 89,492 visited the election page, and 30,016 voted"._ So around 40% of those who visited the site during the election also visited the election page, out of which around 33% voted. These stats need to be improved in the future elections. Maybe some reputation points apart from the bronze Caucus badge and silver Constituent badge will incentivise users to vote?

Comment: Congratulations to all three of you mates! Hope you do your best!

Comment: @YvetteColomb Congo. Move ahead!

Comment: Many congratulations to all the kangaroos. Love their cricket, let see how the mods play their innings!!!

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Because Yvette got more votes than him.

Comment: First of all, congratulations to all newly elected moderators. Just on the side note, looking at the election summary report, FPTP is simpler, doesn't require magic ;) and would give the same results as STV straight away. Maybe time for a change in the next elections?

Comment: this actually is not a question. It should be a question: How was the election? and then an answer with what is provided in the question.

Comment: Congratulations! Go Australia!

Comment: @inetphantom "this actually is not a question. It should be a question" -- No, it shouldn't. What would be the gain in doing that? It would only make the announcement harder to read.

Answer (score 212):

Thank you, Ed and Matt!

I've had the opportunity to interact and learn a lot from you both. Thank you very much for helping me when I was getting started.

Ed, your [mod messages were always a treat to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv1J3.png), and I will certainly miss them in the future.

Even though you both are no longer in the mod room, your helpful userscripts will continue to remind us and the new mods of your legacy.

As for the new mods, Martijn will soon post a picture of how the mod queue looks like. Welcome to the gang, you have got no idea what you're in. I've spent quite a lot of time with all three of you, and I am sure that you'll do a great job as well.

Comment: Thanks, Bhargav! I enjoyed working with you and the rest of the crew.

Comment: Your name looks awkward w/o the diamond, would take some time to get used to it... :(

Comment: I will forever hold the theory that the @EdCottrell who was a mod is in a basement somewhere, sequestered, and that this diamondless Ed isn't the mod we've all grown to love. :D

Comment: @BhargavRao you’re telling me!

Comment: @Patrice shhh. Don’t tell anyone!

Comment: We could just link to the previous sets of images; they all still apply :-) (and I'm a little short on time to find one this time round).

Comment: What do the downvotes on this answer mean?

Comment: Ways to Know the Mod Queue Is Extremely Full #15435: Martijn Pieters is too busy to post something.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That means the button still works

Comment: @VinhVO If there ever was a doubt as to the button's proper functioning, this would be a strange place to test it.

Comment: "Martijn will soon post a picture of how the mod queue looks like" Is this the mandatory picture of a pile of dung and a pitchfork?

Comment: @Lundin yup, as always.

Comment: Congratulation to winners,show your great work from now

Answer (score 68):

Congratulations to you all new Mods: **Rob**, **Samuel** and **Yvette**!

I'm posting here to thank you because you volunteered to share your valuable time with us in order to make our community a better place with your services and I'm happy for you since this services is a chance to grow for all. Winning in an election to serve the community is so great and I hope to find that chance someday.

Now the Spring inspires the spirit of flourishing everywhere I hope SO would be more fruitful with you.

Comment: Considering the previous congratulatory posts were removed, I'm surprised this one's still standing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't understand why congratulatory posts are removed. If you post suck an announcement as a post (a "question"-like), you should be expecting people to respond.

Comment: I work with Spring and I can tell you it inspires no such thing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I assumed the post authors deleted them since they were attracting down votes but like Maroun I don't understand why since the post is inviting people to congratulate the new mods. If they only want people adding comments, not answers, they could make that more clear.

Comment: @BSMP: Only one of them was self-deleted - the rest were either deleted or converted to comments by incumbent mods. I'm guessing this one was kept because it was more than just a couple of lines long. Generally if you can fit your congratulatory message in a very brief comment, you should either do so or even just upvote an existing comment so as not to clutter the thread. Answers do take up a ton of real estate compared to comments of equal length after all.

Comment: @BSMP: Ironically, this is one of those special cases where "short answers ought to be comments" actually applies.

Comment: This is only a congrat message for a temporary situation: Spring 2018 election results. So does it really worth your valuable time to discuss over this answer? Also when I read the other answer I realized it does not reflect my opinions, so I decided to post this answer. After all if it's so important to you all I will delete this answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were getting notifications of all of these comments. Your answer is fine, we were actually talking about the other answers and should have been commenting elsewhere instead of bugging you.

Comment: @BSMP: It's not bugging me. I was thinking everyone is putting such energy to discuss about my unimportant answer :-))

Comment: The Spring only inspires in the Northern hemisphere. From which none of the new moderators are :)