# Reverse the timeline in election history

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-election

I would appreciate if the newest election results were at the top on [the community moderator election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election).

That list will only become longer and needs more scrolling to see the results of the recent election.

Comment: Or maybe make it optional so people can change it themself.

Comment: The _"Make election results great again"_... movement

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: How is this page important (first time seeing it)? I believe there are more useful feature-requests (e.g [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340703/1997232)). If it's an easy change - sure.

Comment: @Sinatr a feature request is a feature request, it doesn't scream "IMPLEMENT ME FIRST!!!!" ...it's there, people up/down vote it, and it's up to Stack staff to prioritize as they see fit ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, too many upvotes. I am afraid timelines will never come to life if such "important" feature-requests will be posted. Still I want to know how important this page, maybe I'll upvote too.

Comment: @Sinatr but the votes don't necessarily correlate to prioritization. Consider the Excel UserVoice ticket for supporting Python (over 4K votes) - yet UserVoice is a small fraction of the feedback community, let alone of the users as a whole, and 4K votes and being the overwhelmingly #1 request there doesn't mean it's the next thing Microsoft should be working on at all. Same here: meta users are but a tiny little fraction of SO users. Staff sees the bigger picture; vote up if you agree, down if you don't, but don't think it means anything wrt priority/importance. All ideas should be brought up.

Comment: @Sinatr: I don't recall how I reached that page. I thought it was because of [the featured question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365198/spring-2018-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1), but it seems none of the links goes there.