# Moderator elected 2018 or 2015?

Tags: bug, moderators

On the [moderators page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) it shows that Ed Cottrell is elected 2018, but the link below points to the Winter 2015 election. Is this a typo or is there a story behind it?

> [image: flair]

Comment: Not since the incident.

Comment: Hey guys do you call November "autumn" or "winter"? (speaking of the northern semisphere)

Comment: @iBug I think November is the end of summer now and February/March time is start of winter these days - that's when the snow usually falls in the UK if it's going to fall. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Snow starts falling in February or March?? That's refreshing

Comment: @iBug Actually..... looking into it further we may only be getting two seasons these days.  [Is It Time to Redefine the Four Seasons?](https://science.howstuffworks.com/nature/climate-weather/atmospheric/climate-change-four-seasons-redefine.htm).

Comment: Ed's username is [elixenide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/elixenide) now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ed Cottrell briefly retired from moderator hood in March 2018. He was re-instated to the position in July 2018, see [Spring 2018 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365198/spring-2018-community-moderator-election-results).

So *both* pieces of information are true, Ed was elected in 2015, then became moderator *again* in 2018. Moderators are elected for life, and so can return from retirement without having to re-run for election.

Comment: I wouldn't formulate it as all _true_, as the phrasing itself is incorrect: "**elected 2018**" is not what happened, there were no won elections in 2018 for him. To be accurate, it should either keep the original _ad vitam_ date (_elected 2015_) or it should either not call it an election for that year (_re-instated 2018_).

Comment: @Cœur: I know, but I don't think this is a common enough issue to require fixing, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it's on Stack Overflow, and it's an inaccurate statement on a page two clicks away from _every page on the site_. Thousands of people are going to read it. That's a common issue. (Then again, it's not _very_ serious.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: thousands of people may briefly skim over the moderators page and *not notice a thing*; Ed's entry is in the middle of 26 entries. *At most a handful of people* will look closely enough to notice the discrepancy. It took a good 6 months for anyone to report it here, for starters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Noting a discrepancy is much harder than noting inaccurate information and not knowing that it's inaccurate.

Comment: Expect a fix for this **bug** in 6-8 weeks :|

Comment: An interesting case to consider if we move away from the election-for-life model as Tim (or was it Jon?) suggested on MSE a while back.

Comment: @TylerH Wikipedia has an "inactivity" rule for admins (equivalent of moderators here): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Inactive_administrators. Subsequently, inactive admins may get their privileges restored but maximum three years after their last activity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Administrators#Restoration_of_adminship

Comment: Great explanation, fallacious statement.  I wish I could both upvote and downvote this post :-)

Comment: FWIW this just happened again with Jon Clements...

Comment: @TylerH while it was 2015 - first elected mod in 2020 or something :p