# Leaving the site and the network - mid election is not the best, but there's no point in staying

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators

This post is a copy of [Time to say goodbye - one less moderator](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/time-to-say-goodbye-one-less-moderator) with some customisations for Stack Overflow.

At the writing of this post I am running in the [12th moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) and am a moderator and the second highest ranking contributor on [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/). I have previously been an [elected moderator on Stack Overflow in 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365198/spring-2018-community-moderator-election-results) and stood down for personal reasons. After which there was a new moderator reinstatement process and I was declined reinstatement due to the object of two or more moderators and certainly not a majority, despite the step down being temporary and the expectation by the community team and moderators I'd return in the new year. I'm not happy about this process, nor Monica's inability to fairly appeal her removal. The process is deeply flawed.

I'm leaving the network. I've requested to have my accounts deleted and want to move on with my life. I no longer enjoy this network. Not so much this site, but Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

I am leaving this note here, as there's so many lovely people here and I owe them an explanation.

I was a founding member of Pets and have first joined Stack Overflow in 2012 and it has been interesting.

I no longer believe in the ethos of the company and I do not like how the Meta sites are run on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. Very little has changed since I first joined the network in 2012 despite having a rigorous Code of Conduct. It seems to be applied subjectively. I also do not want to continue making voluntary contributions to a site that makes money off the back of those contributions and does little to support the contributors.

I hope you, all your loved ones and all your pets are healthy and safe during these strange global times.

Thank you for giving me the honour to serve you on this site. It's been a mixture of pleasure and pain, but there are no regrets. Thank you to all my supporters and I'm sorry to let you down. It's time to live a life with my family and pets. Focusing on things that are rewarding without undue stress. I do understand I make the contact on meta more complex, but I cannot seem to extricate myself from this cycle and no longer care to keep trying. I just want to move on.

I will participate on [Codidact](https://forum.codidact.org/) and hopefully we can start a pets site, as I do enjoy that type of participation. I just don't want to be part of this network.

So [75,000 flags handled later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399162/3956566), I bid you all goodbye.

Take care xx

Love, 
all our horses, dog and cats. 
*neigh neigh, woof, meow purr.*

> **NOTE:** Yvette's account was suspended [at her request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399495/leaving-the-site-and-the-network-mid-election-is-not-the-best-but-theres-no#comment783353_399495)

Comment: _So long, and thanks for all the fish_. Enjoy your life free of the chains of SO/SE. Brightest Blessings.

Comment: @user7412956 thank you!! I plan to! xx

Comment: WOOF!  See you round the food bowl....

Comment: You and I have never interacted before, but I've read much of what you've done in the past as a moderator, and how you've carried yourself in other spaces. Losing you is losing a very, very passionate user, and I seriously wish you all the best as you handle your IRL issues. Good luck, Yvette!

Comment: I'm logging out from this site now and wont' be back. I'll be on Pets a little longer. I've left enough breadcrumbs for those who want to stay in touch to follow. Take care all.

Comment: @Spevacus the irony is I've put in a lot of hours - as have others, but probably a lot more than my critics will ever realise and how many flags were handled. There's only 3-4 mods who consistently handle flags and they take the weight of the entire team and I was one of them. There is one mod who comes and goes without telling us for very long periods. Will handle loads of flags, then nothing. I handled more flags in my 18 months as mod than the majority of mods in years. They will be hard pushed to keep mods who will last the distance. They will stay as mods, but actually don't handle flags.

Comment: I'll miss you. Good luck!

Comment: ok retracting from the moderator election is ok, i wouldn't do the job eitehr, but as you mentioned there a lot of nice people, so simply take a long break and see what comes. the life will go on without you.

Comment: And you shipped this out on a Friday too! :) Stay well, if you do decide to return keep the username, it would be impossible to camouflage your personality and distinctive style. All the best.

Comment: I'm sorry that this is how it ended, but I hope that this will turn out to be a good thing for you. I know that when I finally stepped back from SE it was a good thing for me. The lack of drama is a little weird at first, but you get used to it after a while :)

Comment: A conversation about meta-issues surrounding this announcement, including its featuring and tagging, has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218051/discussion-on-question-by-yvette-leaving-the-site-and-the-network-mid-election). Please, let's keep comments here *directly* relevant to Yvette, her decision to leave, and celebrating her lasting accomplishments/contributions to the site.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you go through all the trouble of reinstatement and nominations just to back out _again_? Is it because you didn't think you stood a chance based on your questionnaire score? FWIW I wanted you back on the team with all your experience as you'd help ease the burden from day one (which is why you were one of my choices) but I see you are running away again. I'm truly disappointed but at the same time wish you the best with whatever you do.

Comment: @cs95 because I'm tired of the crap. It hasn't taken long to feel the stress of meta and I don't want to live through it any more. I don't need it. These people who accuse me of making drama, but are the ones making the noise on the site with comments and posts will have no say in my life and that's a good thing. I have better things to do. As for being elected, who knows who will be elected. No one knows. I always did badly in the questionnaire, it's not connected to the election results.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I actually asked for my account to be deleted earlier and needed to post this *before* the account was deleted, not after. So sorry it's another evil intent on my part "shipping it out on a Friday" I will not miss this site.

Comment: @Yvette sorry to see you go.  i was in the Pet.SE beta with you, and saw your original SO entry and your re-entry.  I've not always agreed with your positions, but I thought you did an excellent job as a moderator and always seemed very fair and unbiased.  Excellent qualities in any moderator.  Sorry to see you go, but given the recent drama, I certainly understand and respect your choice here

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes, I remember those pets days. I worked extremely hard at being objective. I'm dammed whatever I do and it's a loud minority that have forced me off the site. I give up, it's not worth fighting for.

Comment: I don't blame you and have expressed my surprise that you were willing to sacrifice your time and energies again to this site when there was so much else that needed your direct and focused attention. I personally will miss you and all our interactions here and on other sites. You have a wonderful and beautiful spirit and a love of what you do, one that is contagious.  I do wish you, your family, and of course, your horses, good health, a good roof, good food &feed and safety from those who wish you harm. Please contact those of us who care about you from time to time to let us know you are OK

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeh, I've left social media, we need another way of contact, you've been a good friend and it's been interesting to know you also. My daughter and I are starting a new life and as you know my health is not real good. I think I will live longer if I leave the site to be completely honest. I was happy to handle flags, but the meta stress is just not worth it. We've had a lot of change in our lives and we are moving into a much better life and walking away from undue stress. Take care my friend xo

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thank you and I will miss you and many others also. That is the only misgiving. xoxo

Comment: If I am not here... I am mostly on Twitter... I might keep an eye on Codidact :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar we are moving house, so I will try and start a pets site on there in a few months :)

Comment: Does feeding 30+ birds counts as having pets ;)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar of course! And birds are best left out of cages anyway. what sort of birds?

Comment: Mostly sparrows... some tits, few common blackbirds, occasional robin...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar lovely. We had a family of magpies at one of our homes and the babies would take food from my hand, the parents would watch. Birds are beautiful. We want to get chickens when we move.

Comment: @CodyGray the moderation you've done on this post is the most supported I've ever felt by you, in fact probably the only time I've felt support from you. Thank you. It's a good way to end things. Take care. I've asked Catija to suspend my account and change the username until it can be deleted. Bye

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go. You seemed to really care, and you had my vote. I didn't think flagging a comment hostile to you would spiral out of control.

Comment: Without touching on the election or the past, from one human being to another, on the off chance that you see this: Take care of yourself and those (human or animal) that you care about. Mental health is important, and it's important to take the time to care for it. I hope you and yours stay well.

Comment: I'm saddened by this, but given what I've seen, I understand. Good luck in the house move and everything else going on, and see you over in Codidact.

Comment: I'm not even sure if I should retract my vote for you now, Yvette. Take care. Was nice having you around. Running again as moderator is not fair. Never was, never will be. People will compare your past interactions with you as moderator with the blank slate other candidates have.

Comment: 75k flags is really a lot, probably hundreds of hours given to the community, that seems to have developed into a wrong direction in your eyes. Nevertheless, thanks for all the hard work and all the best in the future on codidact or elsewhere.

Comment: I don't understand. A few weeks ago you were willing to give it another shot and now you're not happy with SO. What happened?

Comment: @Mast Can only guess from the outside - there have been 2 groups around Yvette: One which supports her, and an other who is, let's say, very critical of her. Things get nasty. Members of one group flag everything the other group does that relates to Yvette, comments either as unfriendly or unkind, or as no longer needed (depending on the group). Moderators have to step in, deleting comments. [People ask about deleted comments.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399436/) In the middle is Yvette, who just want her old position back - which was promised at the time she left.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Is the very critical group aligned with "the company" or "the community" or "none of the above"? It's hard for me to imagine that it would be aligned with "the community" (defined as that part of the community not affiliated with the company), and if it is aligned with "the company" this would be an even sadder event for SO. On the other hand, if it is some "sub community," that provides a dimension to this huge conflict that I had no idea about until now...

Comment: I don't think either "side" is closely tied to any specific side in the broader "company" vs "community" debate, same as Yvette hasn't neccessarily been directly on the side of SE even in the cases where she acted seemingly against the "community". It's quite a heterogenous conflict. She is simply a rather polarizing character who carries her strong personality rather expressively, you either like that or you find it inappropriate.

Comment: @JosiahYoder No idea. If you have 10k, you can see deleted answers, one on this question, an other in the question I linked, that can give you some insight. I have no idea how organized those both groups are - if they actively coordinate in a chat room or if everyone just does the same for the same reasons.

Comment: Now I find it safe to admit: I was never going to vote for you this round. Not because I hate you or think you are a bad moderator, quite the opposite actually: as a person, as much as I got to know you in chat and through your epic Youtube ramblings, I like you quite a lot. I saw up close what being a moderator/deeply invested in the site did to you the last time around, this election for you was far too soon. Unfortunately, this finalisation event proves that beyond a shadow of a doubt. I also know that this is not the first time you have done this, so I hope you will be back again.

Comment: This is exactly why I voted for her the first go around and not the second.  Good luck Yvette.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Shoot, I'll make my comment an answer

Yvette, I don't blame you for what you are doing and as you know, have expressed my utter surprise that you were willing to sacrifice your time and energies again to this site when there was so much else that needed your direct and focused attention. I personally will miss you and all our interactions here and on other sites. You have a wonderful and beautiful spirit and a love of what you do, one that is contagious. I do wish you, your family, and of course, your horses, good health, a good roof, good food & feed, and safety from those who wish you harm.

**Please** contact those of us who care about you from time to time to let us know you and your family are OK

Comment: yeh, I've left social media, we need another way of contact, you've been a good friend and it's been interesting to know you also. My daughter and I are starting a new life and as you know my health is not real good. I think I will live longer if I leave the site to be completely honest. I was happy to handle flags, but the meta stress is just not worth it. We've had a lot of change in our lives and we are moving into a much better life and walking away from undue stress. Take care my friend xo

Comment: It didn't take long for the reality of the stress of meta to bring back memories and the break did me well, as I don't want it anymore and it had become assimilated as normal until the break. Take care also through this covid, it's strange times and the world is in crisis.

Comment: I am sorry to see you go Yvette, and hope you can read new comments to you, even though your accounts are now locked. You demonstrated a passion and a humaneness for helping people on the network through moderation activity and policy lobbying, and I do not doubt that some of the conversations have been exhausting. I don't doubt that you have been relieved of a burden, and I wish you good health and happiness for the future. You will be missed.

Answer (score 68):

You’ve been an important part of this network for many years and instrumental in keeping the quality of our content high. Thank you for that effort! The number of flags you've handled is impressive and worthy of respect. You've also worked very hard to guide users on how to be successful. It's good to know that you'll be taking time to focus on your family life and your pets. We respect your decision to step down and wish you a very restful and stress-free future! In time, we hope to see you around the network too. Please know that your contributions here will not be forgotten.

We've rarely needed to remove someone mid-election and don't have a built-in way to do it but we wanted to respect your request - we've edited your nomination to note that you've been withdrawn and inform voters that they can update their selections in the election. Fortunately, the Single Transferable Vote (aka STV) method we use is robust because it allows voters to rank their top candidates rather than only a single choice and OpaVote supports withdrawing candidates when processing ballots.

Comment: Thank you. I will be glad to have it over. It makes me sick and I will not miss it to be honest.

Comment: There has to be some way of notifying SO users that Yvette's nomination has been withdrawn. If not for following the featured post, I would not have known and my vote would have been lost.

Comment: @Boaz Perhaps the featured post *is* the way of notifying SO users... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray With two days left for the elections, I suspect many votes are still cast for Yvette. The site has  a special alert shown at the top in some scenarios. Why not use it? These elections are already not a huge success, with very few candidates and now the most qualified of them leaving.

Answer (score 66):

There's not much else that I can really *say* without it going too far in one direction or another, but at the minimum...

- I'm glad that you're deciding to take care of yourself.  If it means that you don't want to do what is easily the most thankless job around these parts, then that's perfectly acceptable to me.
- I'm glad that you're willing to accept that you don't want to be a moderator, and I will let your reasons be your own.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218057/discussion-on-answer-by-makoto-leaving-the-site-and-the-network-mid-election-i).

Comment: This response could be improved, without going too far in one direction or another, by thanking Yvette for her work as an SO moderator.

Answer (score 36):

I really regret seeing you go.

I especially liked seeing your contributions on meta. You clearly cared strongly for this community, and freely shared your opinion, which was often distinct from what had been shared before. The voting system on meta seems to promote groupthink, so I strongly value different views, even when I might not agree with them.

You also brought a human side to meta and to moderation, and promoted informal communication through chat on meta when it was needed, while still moving an enormous amount of work on flags and moderation.

I fully support you choosing your own well-being, and hope you and all your animals are well. I don't think we'll ever quite find another moderator like you, but hope you inspired others to share their opinion even when it might not be the most popular one, and consider the human side to their action and who they impact.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I want to accept this and hovercraft's answer. I'm torn. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399509/3956566

Answer (score 7):

It is very much a shame to see a good senior user and moderator go. I mostly lurk on meta but have seen the good work and discussion you have created in the community.

That being said, and I will be blunt, unless something has radically changed between the beginning of the moderator election and now, I feel that your entering the election was disingenuous. As someone who was going to vote for you, I feel somewhat betrayed. Thankfully the flexibility of the voting allows for us to change. If not, I would be very frustrated, as my vote would have been completely lost. If you felt this strongly about things, the correct thing would have been to not enter the election, or to at least make clear your candidacy as protest, like CrazyPython.

I do not intend for this to be mean, simply to voice an opinion that others may share. I hope your efforts in other communities are successful.

Comment: "my vote would have been completely lost" - no. Your vote would move to your second preference.

Comment: If there were four people I considered to be good candidates for moderator, and I cast a vote for someone who dropped out, that vote is gone. My fourth candidate does not get my vote. This is not hypothetical. Not everyone visits meta frequently and may not be aware of this change before the election ends.

Comment: But something awful could have happened in the real world  after the beginning of the moderator election. We don't know.

Comment: @code11: No, you can change your votes as many times as you want up until the end of the election, including the order and removing a vote for Yvette.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen - "something awful could have happened in the real world after the beginning of the moderator election" - quite right, we should certainly give the benefit of the doubt. But that doesn't change code11's point, because they said "unless something has radically changed between the beginning of the moderator election and now".

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoyed your contributions. I was using another account (whusky_live66). I’m pretty sure you forgot me, but you helped me and my pet really much.

I came back to this site for the coding section and I just saw your post as suggestion. 
 I’m only sad to see that this site is losing one of his best contributors.

I hope you have better time with your loved ones :) (my *Whisky* is dead since 2018/10/22... But you helped me and her with your great advice :D and other users helped me too, but you were always with the best advice :) I did take care on the best way until I couldn’t more sadly enough.

Comment: Are *"whusky"* and *"Whisky"* two different things in this context (it could be a ***real*** typo)?

Comment: No my dogs name was Whisky lol it is a Husky but I (and my partner) thought Whisky would be a cool name you know :D

Comment: Just to add more clarity my username was whUsky because I thought otherwise it would be a littlebit repulsive :)

Answer (score 0):

> Very little has changed since I first joined the network in 2012 despite having a rigorous Code of Conduct. It seems to be applied subjectively.

What,

- the code of conduct didn't help things?
- the code of conduct was misused and applied in a problematic fashion?

why, I am shocked. Shocked and chagrined. However could this *be*? If only we had been forewarned this might happen...

Anyway, I didn't have much interaction with Yvette, but I'm sad to see a moderator leave in these circumstances.

Comment: * _Former_ moderator.

Answer (score -13):

It is late now since you are now suspended but I do hope you read this.
I read your posts on Pets.SE and I do see you as a very passionate person -- someone who cares.

Your technical answers there are quite informative and polite.

Please reconsider your decision of leaving the whole network and stay on Pets.SE.

Everyone is not suited to every role but I never wanted you to leave the whole network. There are some things you are excellent at and I have seen that in your writings on Pets.SE.

Your efforts and dedication at Pets.SE will be missed.

Comment: I am just an average user, don't know what goes on in moderator circles.  I was just reading this out of curiosity. But I have to wander about the -14 votes here. What's with that?  I am guessing this does not "answer" anything, but this is one of those strange goodbye "questions".  Still the other "answers" got up to +50 votes... Curious

Comment: @code_fodder - The person who posted this answer was fairly critical of Yvette in recent days. I imagine the downvotes are from people who followed the going ons on meta in  the the last week and find this post disingenuous.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica tells a lot about people when they shoot the messenger even when the message is positive and constructive.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Interesting perespective. I like it. I am surprised though how my post "disingenuous"! Here I have talked only about the part of Yvette which I liked - which is her writing and active participation on Pets.SE. I am still disapointed of her behavior as a moderator candidate but I haven't criticized her here for that.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl - Let's not play coy here, shall we? You may have raised important points under her nomination, but your critique ventured *very* close to attacking her entire character. Is it *that* surprising that this answer rings hollow when that context is present in people's minds?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `attacking her entire character.` Well, I am not still feeling positive of her behaviour as a moderator candidate and whatever I wrote under her post is what I felt about her -- I have no regrets. But -- that has nothing to do with her technical skills on Pets.SE for which I am praising her. Anyways, I perfectly okay if this post sounds hollow to you. Thank you for explaining the downvotes.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. How can someone be a good moderator on one site, but not an another? I'd expect the tasks and procedures are fairly identical.

Comment: @Scratte Not taking sides here, but Stack Overflow is special. If from a large group of people a thousand would be good moderators on Stack Exchange, a lot less of them would have it in them to deal with the garbage pit that Stack Overflow is. Moderators themselves have compared it to shovelling shit. It's much less dire on the other sites, thankfully.

Comment: `How can someone be a good moderator on one site, but not an another?`  Being a moderator is NOT only about handling flags. Handling flags is one small part of being a moderator. Major part of being a moderator is about knowing when to keep your mouth shut, when to bite your tongue, when to speak, how to speak without bias, how to control your temper and keep calm while speaking, etc.  ------ A person may be good at handling flags but I won't want this person as a moderator if their social behaviour is ridiculous, if they are a hypocrite. ------  @Scratte

Comment: ----- (continued) ... Other sites like Arts&Crafts, Pets, Writing etc. are tiny sites, they don't have any drama in them. Metas of SO and SE are very volatile places where a person has to tread carefully. Therefore if a person is a moderator on a tiny site that doesn't mean they are fit to moderate huge sites too. @Scratte

Comment: Agreeing with @Aquarius_Girl. Effort and passion alone is not enough. As a mod you need to be able to keep your calm, step in at the right time, and being able to judge and de-escalate a situation. On SO meta, IMO Yvette was not doing enough of that, and I share these concerns. It's a tough critique to give, because it can (and did, apparently) feel very personal. Nevertheless, I think this answer is not disingenuous at all. To me it feels very honest to openly speak your (valid) concerns while at the same time acknowledging the positives about post quality, passion and effort.