# Are there views Meta does not approve of?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

It's not a big deal but a comment I left on [Leaving the site and the network - mid election is not the best, but there's no point in staying](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399495/leaving-the-site-and-the-network-mid-election-is-not-the-best-but-theres-no) , basically commiserating with Yvette on her leaving, was removed without explanation.
If one's comments, which I don't believe were rude or abusive are going to be sent down a black-hole for unknown reasons, what's the point of engaging on Meta?
It seems that if your view doesn't chime with the "collective", it will be erased.
Any way, as long as I know, goodbye and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: Comments are deleted all the time. Some mods oblige on comment flags more than other mods. Comments being deleted being right or wrong, the usual advice is: if you want to post something that you think has lasting value, post it as a question or answer; comments can be deleted at any time; if only to clean up under a very  busy/noisy  post.

Comment: Can we just let this thing go now?

Comment: (That being said, "meta"  is  a [collection of individuals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QereR0CViMY), including yourself, so  it's bound  to include a lot of different and contrasting  viewpoints; there are very few, if any, subjects for which you  could say there is a "canonical  meta opinion")

Comment: I read your comment. While it wasn't directly rude, I remember it to be a little dismissive of the new members. But I do not believe in censuring meta, though I do agree that comment threads are exhausting at times.

Comment: Mine was deleted too: I said "You don't know me neither do I know you. Bubye Yvette!". AFAIK, It doesn't break any rules.

Comment: @TheMaster Yours was flagged as "no longer needed" and deleted by a moderator. Can't say I disagree. You admit that neither of you know each other, and you didn't offer any particularly unique wisdom, so what, exactly, were you expecting it to bring to the discussion? Why should it crowd out other, more meaningful comments?

Comment: I hope you're not implying you're going to leave the site completely over *one deleted comment*. That's a complete overreaction, especially from an experienced user who should be fully aware that comments are second-class citizens and subject to deletion at any given time.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah... new to meta and never used/seen that flag.  Just wanted to say goodbye.

Comment: "No longer needed" is a comment flag across the Stack Exchange network; it's not unique to Meta.

Comment: @TheMaster consider using the word "goodbye" to say goodbye. People can't see your intentions, they can only see what and how you write something so you had better make that as precise as possible. "Bubye" sounds like you're talking down to a child especially when addressing someone you don't know.

Comment: "It seems that if your view doesn't chime with the "collective", it will be erased." That is assuming bad intentions. You are a user for at least 5 years with lots of reputation. Is this really the first time, a comment of yours gets deleted? I see my comments vanish on a daily basis and while I do not necessarily agree with that I don't think it's a thought police going after them. Assuming that mods just have a different view on an average lifetime of a comment is much closer a possible explanation.

Comment: @F1Krazy Specifically `Meta`. It's feels like Twitter or Facebook

Comment: @ivarni I think the last time Meta just let something go was sometime in 2016.

Comment: @BSMP And you still remember it!

Answer (score 32):

Your comment was deleted by a staff member when cleaning up an exchange between two other users that had outlived its usefulness and devolved into petty bickering. It is possible that your comment just got inadvertently deleted, or it's possible that they intentionally deleted it because something in it caught their eye. I'm really not sure.

Nor am I especially interested in further litigating the deletion of comments. We've done enough of that recently.

> If one's comments, which I don't believe were rude or abusive are going to be sent down a black-hole for unknown reasons, what's the point of engaging on Meta?

If you want to "engage" on Meta with the assurance that others will see it, please do so in an answer.

> It seems that if your view doesn't chime with the "collective", it will be erased.

This takes a far too conspiratorial tone for me to engage. That's not true at all. I and other members of the moderator team try very hard to keep it from becoming that way. As such, I'm a bit sensitive to accusations otherwise.

Comments on Yvette's departure notice have been moderated a bit more heavily than is typical for Meta posts. There are several reasons for that. First, there's a lot of controversy and drama wrapped up there, regardless of which side you are on, all of which is still fresh and resulting in a large number of comments. Even if well-intentioned, these comments have no place anymore. Yvette is no longer a candidate in the election, so discussing her suitability for moderator is no longer necessary. Furthermore, criticisms just aren't really appropriate in someone's departure notice. There's a time and place for criticism, and that ain't it.

---

Because I can't help myself, here's your comment:

> It's sad but common for those that built it, to be deemed superfluous, as time passes. New brooms! They have little concept of the effort that was needed to get the ball rolling. Best bow out with dignity and leave the new crowd to effentually drive it into the ground due to their lack of understanding of the nature of the beast, than to go down with it. Best of luck and happiness for the future.

I assume that *"leave the new crowd to effentually drive it into the ground due to their lack of understanding of the nature of the beast, than to go down with it"* was considered to be somewhat rude. As is dismissing the other moderator candidates as *"new brooms"*. It's also just flat wrong—of the other folks running for moderator, I can personally vouch that all but one of them has just as good an understanding of the nature of this site as Yvette, and they have also put in a significant amount of effort towards making this site what it is today.

Comment: Isn't there a saying "new brooms, sweeo clean"? I certainly expect all the candidates to dust off some forgotten corners when they come into office....

Comment: I believe the full saying is, "a new brush sweeps clean, but an old brush knows the corners", implying that experience is valuable. But yes, I expect there to be a lot of dusting. And tarring and feathering. @rene

Comment: @CodyGray I tip my hat for the fact that you took the time to reply at length. So thank you for that. "Deleted in error" or "outlasted its usefulness" both seem a little thin. I'm far too old and experienced (in life, if not SO) to not see the writing on the wall. I'll stick to answering questions, as that at least, is not yet beset with politics but even that's changing. Once the "tarring and feathering", along with the "dusting" have been completed, you need to look about yourself and ask what is left? Will it be a shiny new citadel or a clean echo chamber?